# Integer polynomial with two aligned roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, integer-lattices

Anyone have an example of a monic polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ with $f(0)=1$ such that for $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}\backslash\mathbb{R}$ and $t \in R, t>0, t\neq 1$ both $\alpha$ and $t\alpha$ are roots of f(x)?

Comment: Do you mean for *any* $\alpha \in \Bbb C$, or just *some*  $\alpha$ that we pick?

Comment: @RobertLewis For any $\alpha \in \mathbb C$ would be great, but if you have an example for a particular $\alpha$ is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  There are a minimum of four roots. What are they? Have you tried writing down the multiplication of the four terms and see where it leads?  It looks to me like any $\alpha$ with integral (real part and modulus squared) and any integral $t$ (other than $1$) work.

Comment: Yes I did it but I couldn't solve it. The case $\alpha$ with integral(real part and modulus squared) and integral t is incompatible with the condition $f(0)=1$. I think that $t$ can not be rational.

Comment: I missed the $f(0)=1$.  How about $(x^2+4)(x^2+\frac 14)=x^4+\frac 94x^2+1$ with roots $2i,-2i,\frac 12i,-\frac 12i$

Comment: But your polynomial is not in $\mathbb Z [x]$. I need a monic polynomial in $\mathbb Z [x]$.